# How do I customize the switch to make the circle relatively smaller in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, switch-statement

This is the required switch
[Required/expected switch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lc0E.png)

I am using flutter's Switch widget to do this but I'm unable to get closer to the required switch. Using Transform to increase the size of the switch but increases the size of the entire switch. Any ideas as to how I can match the image given?
This is where I am at:
[Where I am at](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x70Zn.png)

Answer (score 0):

The `Switch` widget use the adaptative mode, and if you check the source code, you will find something like this:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    switch (widget._switchType) {
      case _SwitchType.material:
        return buildMaterialSwitch(context);

      case _SwitchType.adaptive: {
        final ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);
        assert(theme.platform != null);
        switch (theme.platform) {
          case TargetPlatform.android:
          case TargetPlatform.fuchsia:
            return buildMaterialSwitch(context);
          case TargetPlatform.iOS:
            return buildCupertinoSwitch(context);
        }
      }
    }
    assert(false);
    return null;
  }
}
```

It will use the `buildMaterialSwitch` method for `Android` and `buildCupertinoSwitch` for iOS.

Checking the `buildCupertinoSwitch` method:

```
  Widget buildCupertinoSwitch(BuildContext context) {
    final Size size = getSwitchSize(Theme.of(context));
    return Container(
      width: size.width,  // Same size as the Material switch.
      height: size.height,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: CupertinoSwitch(
        dragStartBehavior: widget.dragStartBehavior,
        value: widget.value,
        onChanged: widget.onChanged,
        activeColor: widget.activeColor,
      ),
    );
  }
```

That's the key, then you have to use `CupertinoSwitch` widget :), just don't forget to add the import:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
```